# Getting file icons (QFileIconProvider::icon) in non-gui thread

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, icons

I'm trying to get file icons from non-gui thread to avoid gui freeze. I'm getting the warning:

> QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

Is there a way to solve my problem? Maybe there is another simple way to get file icons? My target system is Ubuntu, I don't need to support other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `QImage` instead to load file-icons which can be used outside **GUI thread**. And then you can use any function provided by `QImage` to convert it into `QPixmap`. For example following `static` function:

```
QPixmap QImage::fromImage (const QImage & image, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags)
```

Comment: The problem is QFileIconProvider uses QPixmap internally. I cannot change it.